# Distinct records in Query matching for Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following record set in elastic search

```
POST /books/book/1
{
  "title" : "JavaScript: The Good Parts",
  "author" : "Douglas Crockford",
  "language" : "JavaScript",
  "publishYear" : 2009,
  "soldCopy" : "50"
}

POST /books/book/2
{
  "title" : "JavaScript: The Good Parts",
  "author" : "Douglas Crockford",
  "language" : "JavaScript",
  "publishYear" : 2009,
  "soldCopy" : "110"
}

POST /books/book/3
{
  "title" : "JavaScript: The Good Parts",
  "author" : "Douglas Crockford1",
  "language" : "JavaScript",
  "publishYear" : 2011,
  "soldCopy" : "2"
}

POST /books/book/4
{
  "title" : "JavaScript: The Good Parts",
  "author" : "Douglas Crockford2",
  "language" : "JavaScript",
  "publishYear" : 2012,
  "soldCopy" : "5"
}
```

I am using the following elastic search query to get the distinct title and author based on a given year 2009.The output for the query that i am expecting is

```
JavaScript: The Good Parts Douglas Crockford
```

but in the response i get back 2 records with same ouput like :

```
JavaScript: The Good Parts      Douglas Crockford
JavaScript: The Good Parts      Douglas Crockford
```

Query used for elastic search was :

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "publishYear": "2009"   }
  }
}
```

equivalent select query that i am try to create in database terms is :

```
select distinct title,author from book where publishYear = '2009'
```

How could i get the same output from elastic search as my sql query ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Distinct in sql is equivalent to [terms aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) in elasticsearch.

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "publishYear": "2009"
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "unique_author": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "author",
        "size": 10
      }
    },
    "unique_book": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "title",
        "size": 10
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 0
}
```

For this to work you would have to make title and author field as **not_analyzed** or you could also use `keyword tokenizer` with `lowercase` token filter. The better option would be to make them [multi fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-fields.html)

You could create index like this

```
PUT books
{
  "mappings": {
    "book":{
      "properties": {
        "title":{
          "type": "string",
          "fields": {
            "raw":{
              "type": "string",
              "index": "not_analyzed"
            }
          }
        },
        "author":{
          "type": "string",
          "fields": {
            "raw":{
              "type": "string",
              "index": "not_analyzed"
            }
          }
        },
        "language":{
          "type": "string"
        },
        "publishYear":{
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "soldCopy":{
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then use *.raw* in aggregation.

Comment: what does "size": 10 and "size": 0 mean in this query

Comment: outer size:0 means ES will only give you aggregation results and not search results. size:10 inside aggregation will restrict the distinct author and title to top 10 results.

Comment: Also if i need the same query to have IN operator in publishYear column like select distinct title,author from book where publishYear in(2009,2010) .How can we do that

Comment: you can use [date](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-date-format.html) type for publishyear and then do range query or you can use [terms query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html)

Comment: is the terms query available for 2.3 version of elastic search?

Comment: yes, [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/query-dsl-terms-query.html)

Comment: My output looks something like this after using the above approach in the aggregations section :"aggregations": {
"unique_author": {
"doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
"sum_other_doc_count": 0,
"buckets": [
{
"key": "crockford",
"doc_count": 2
}
,
{
"key": "douglas",
"doc_count": 2
}
]
},
"unique_book": {
"doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
"sum_other_doc_count": 0,
"buckets": [
{
"key": "good",
"doc_count": 2
}
,
{
"key": "javascript",
"doc_count": 2
}
,
{
"key": "parts",
"doc_count": 2
}
,
{
"key": "the",
"doc_count": 2
}
]
}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127177/discussion-between-chintanshah25-and-user3290807).

Comment: no worries , i got the desired output after adding the .raw in aggregation query